# Custom function has an if and it gets executed before function

Tags: php, if-statement, cookies, php-7

I have a function to change my website's language and inside this function there is an if statement which chooses between two languages (Turkish and English) but before i run the function the if statement works and conditions apply i want to wait until after the function is executed.

```php
setcookie("language", "tr", time()+(86400 * 365), "/", $vars->networkSite);
function langUrl(){
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['language'])) {
        $GLOBALS['langswitch'] = "EN";
        $GLOBALS['language'] = "TR";

    } elseif ($_COOKIE['language'] === "tr") {
        setcookie("language", "en", time()+(86400 * 365), "/", $vars->networkSite);
        $GLOBALS['langswitch'] = "EN";
        $GLOBALS['language'] = "TR";

    } elseif ($_COOKIE['language'] === "en") {
        setcookie("language", "tr", time()+(86400 * 365), "/", $vars->networkSite);
        $GLOBALS['langswitch'] = "TR";
        $GLOBALS['language'] = "EN";

    }

}

<button class="nav-link languageShortHand" type="submit" value="<? langUrl(); ?>"><?= $GLOBALS['langswitch'] ?></button>
```

I want to execute if after executing the function. Thanks for your help in advance

PS: If I try to run this code like this every time I refresh the page language switches. You can see the problem on https://umutore.com

Comment: "i want to wait until after the function is executed" - what does that mean? PHP code is executed line by line, so if you want to run some code after another has executed, just place it behind

Comment: I meant after i used the button then running the function thus setting cookie after clicking the button

Comment: As PHP runs on the server, and Javascript in the browser, you should simply submit the form (using a usual form or AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the function seems to be wrong. You're executing it by doing `<? langUrl(); ?>`, seemingly expecting it to return a URL. What it does in reality is assign global values, not returning anything.

So you are executing the function and it works as intended. What is it that you want to do?

Comment: I wanna execute the function when i click tto the button then change the value of the cookie

Comment: The function itself sets the cookie, but the button is not responsible for executing the function. You need to make it so that the function executes when the button is pressed by checking in the PHP for whether or not to press the button. Forms are one way.

Comment: can you send an example or the code itself, i'm really confused by this problem to be honest

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['language'])) {

    $GLOBALS['langswitch'] = "EN";

} elseif ($_COOKIE['language'] === "tr") {

    $GLOBALS['langswitch'] = "EN";

} elseif ($_COOKIE['language'] === "en") {
    $GLOBALS['langswitch'] = "TR";

}
function languageSwitch (){
    if ($GLOBALS['langswitch'] == "EN"){
        echo "en";
    } elseif ($GLOBALS['langswitch'] == "TR"){
        echo "tr";
    }
}
if ($_POST['language'] == "tr"){
    $GLOBALS['langswitch'] = "EN";
    echo "test1";
} elseif ($_POST['language'] == "en"){
    $GLOBALS['langswitch'] = "TR";
    echo "test2";
}
 if ($GLOBALS['langswitch'] === "EN") {
    setcookie("language", "tr", time()+(86400 * 365), "/", $vars->networkSite);
} elseif ($GLOBALS['langswitch'] === "TR"){
    setcookie("language", "en", time()+(86400 * 365), "/", $vars->networkSite);
}
```

and using form like this

```
<form class="vertical-align position-relative" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<button class="nav-link languageShortHand" type="submit" value="<? languageSwitch();?>" name="language"><?=  $GLOBALS['langswitch'] ?></button>
</form>
```

fixed the problem thanks to the suggestion of TemporaryName